# Renaming columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Could someone please help me with renaming columns? I have a large dataset with about 150 columns and I need to rename each of the columns. I've been looking for the answer for the past 2 hours and I just can't find anything. I know how to use the basic function 'rename', but I'm pretty sure there is an easier and quicker way to do it than just renaming each columns one by one? Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have some patterns to rename your columns?

Comment: Yes, I just wanna rename to to 'Special1', 'Special2'...'Special150' , so yea there is a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rename it directly, like:

```
df.columns = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

In your case you can use:

```
df.columns = ['Special{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(0, len(df.columns))]
```

Comment: Or... `df.columns = [f'Special{n}' for n, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1)]`...

Comment: @JonClements Oh, you are right, we should use {} for strings. Thank you. It's faster and better. But doing it with generators is still faster then with enumirate

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.columns = 'Special' + pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.columns)+1).astype(str)
print(df.columns)

# Output
Index(['Special1', 'Special2', 'Special3', 'Special4', 'Special5', 'Special6',
       'Special7'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: @Akub. You can also try `df.columns = 'Special' + pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.columns)+1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)`

Comment: @Corralien why should we use pd.RangeIndex if it is much slower? If we use python generator it's faster more then in 4 times, I have checked it

Comment: @Corralien - ah perfect, the second works as well! Thanks so much

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia. For 150 columns do you think speed is important?